# Changing background color in excel results in a ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl, valueerror

I cannot change the background color of a cell in excel through python code with openpyxl. Every time I run the script it returns 'ValueError: Colors must be aRGB hex values', despite the fact that I am using aRGB hex values.

```py
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
redFill = PatternFill(bgColor="#FFFF6A1F", fill_type="solid")
wb['A1'].fill = redFill
wb.save('path to example.xlsx')
```

I tried using normal hex values, I tried using 'start_color' instead of 'bgColor', I tried updating openpyxl but I have the latest version and all of that returned the exact same error. Any ideas/solutions?

Comment: I don't think you need the `#`, and that might be the cause of the error.

Comment: Omg that was it, I hate it when it's that simple, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct except that when you have your hex code you do not need to have a #. So the code would look like this.

```
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
redFill = PatternFill(bgColor="FFFF6A1F", fill_type="solid")
wb['A1'].fill = redFill
wb.save('path to example.xlsx')
```

I hope this helps.